# How to populate a Mailchimp newsletter with latest events from Wordpress plugin EventOn?

Tags: plugins, events, automation, plugin-mailchimp

Once a month I send a newsletter with upcoming events. I also publish all the event on a wordpress site with EventOn. I was wondering if there is a way to import the latest events in a mailchimp newsletter. Now I enter all the events manually, which is tedious. Any tips welcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to get an RSS feed from EventOn and then create an RSS Campaign in Mailchimp and pull in the event items automatically using that RSS feed.

- [Configuring RSS Feed in EventOn](http://www.myeventon.com/documentation/how-to-set-up-rss-addon/)
- [Using RSS Content Blocks in Mailchimp](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/content-blocks/use-rss-items-content-blocks)

PS This is really not the right forum for this question, but hope this helps :)

Comment: This is great thanks. Sorry for posting in the wrong forum...